# How to reference/link another project in grails workspace without using jar files?

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a Grails website that references a java core application. I have been successful in adding a .jar dependency to that project; however the java project is in the same workspace as my grails project and I would ultimately like to reference that project directly. I don't want to deal with the added step of creating a new jar file every time that there is a modification to the java project, cleaning and updating my dependencies.
I added the java project to my grails' project "Java Build Path" and at first everything seemed to work fine, but when I run grails>compile, the compiler fails to resolve all imports that point to the java project.

I am using Spring Source Toolsuite as my IDE.

Comment: Have you considered using Maven for your dependent project? When you build your Jar project it will store the jar in your .m2 Maven repository (local). Then you can reference that jar in your Grails project via the `BuildConfig.groovy` file. It will pickup any new jar files when Grails runs but it won't automatically build your jar project. You could use Jenkins to do that though.

Comment: @nickdos, I don't like Maven. I am currently using jar files, which is essentially the same deal, but without using Maven. Eventually, I will setup Ivy or Ant. Even with Maven, I would essentially be using the jar files, which isn't exactly what I would like to have.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the project to the "Deployment Assembly" path (same level as "Java Build Path" in the properties menu)?

Comment: I don't have that option in Groovy/Grails Tool Suite